# iPhone NSURLConnection through Proxy+Auth

Tags: iphone, proxy, nsurlconnection, cfnetwork

I am using NSURLConnection to make connections to a server, through a proxy that requires authentication this fails. The proxy settings are set under the WiFi, but the connection still fails. I believe there is a part of CFNetwork that can fix this, but this might be just for streams and I am unsure of how to implement it with NSURLConnection. How can I tell my application to use the proxy settings set under WiFi?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use the delegate method

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```